# Find Maximum from the column in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, qliksense

I am very much new to HIVE. I am working with QLiksense and HIVE.
I have a table with year,month,day.
I loaded the table and concatenated as,

```
Load year&''&month''&day as concatdate;
SQL select * from HIVE. 'abc'. 'def'; 

Load ...
..
(the other fields)
..
..
SQL select * from HIVE. 'abc'. 'def';
```

Now I want to find the maximum of the concatdate and retrieve those rows alone in HIVE. The year month and day is string type.

Please do help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a subquery:

```
select h.*
from hive.abc.def h
where h.concatdate = (select max(h2.concatdate) from hive.abc.def h2);
```